# Is there some way to handle a disconnect in DB uri?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am wondering is there some way to set `pool_pre_ping` in the Database URI so that I should not touch the actual code and use some `SELECT[1]` type of conn checks?

In the config, next following variable is read:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@db:5432/{db}'
```

I would like to add `pool_pre_ping` setting like:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@db:5432/{db} [SOMETHING pool_pre_ping=True]'
```

A problem behind the need for setting pool_pre_ping is that client side occasionally shuts down a db connection and an application can not offer response. Before fixing the original reason for this problem I should prevent disconnections.. on way or another. I am working with Docker containers.

I am very thanksful if you could offer me some tips. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

This was recently made much easier to achieve in Flask-SQLAlchemy v2.4.

The `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` configuration key has been added specifically to make the configuration of `create_engine` through your flask app less rigid ([docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#configuration)). So in your case adding `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {"pool_pre_ping": True}` will achieve what you want.

Alternatively (again 2.4+), you can pass the dict of keyword arguments to the `engine_options` parameter of the `SQLAlchemy()` constructor ([docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#configuration)), e.g., `SQLAlchemy(app, engine_options={"pool_pre_ping": True})` is equivalent to above, except that these values will merge with and take precedence over any engine settings also defined in `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! Now it works :-)

I did following:

(I did not set up "pool_pre_ping" in URI but added some lines in the code)

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as _NSQLAlc
...

class SQLAlchemy(_NSQLAlc):
    def apply_pool_defaults(self, app, options):
        super(SQLAlchemy, self).apply_pool_defaults(app, options)
        options["pool_pre_ping"] = True

db = SQLAlchemy()